# How to let the last column of a CSS Grid with auto-fit shrink bellow the min value of minmax?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am using the following CSS Grid layout:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(500px, 1fr));
}
```

This tries to fit as many 500px columns as possible then dispatches the remaining space evenly amongst the columns.

The problem is that when there is only one column left (grid width < 1000px) the column will shrink until it reaches 500px and will not shrink more than that, even if the grid gets smaller, causing the column to overflow.

I've tried many combinations, including nesting minmax functions, but could not solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider `max-width` on your elements using `vw` unit. Simply pay attention to maring/padding/border in order to identify the correct value.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(500px, 1fr));
}

.grid>span {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  max-width:100vw;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(100%,500px), 1fr));
```

The `min(100%, ...)` should allow your grid-item to be smaller than 500px when the parent of the grid-container is smaller than that.

Answer (score -3):

I think this will help

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(5,500px);
```

Comment: This creates 5 columns of 500px and does not solve the issue. I'd like to keep the behavior of auto-fit and minmax which creates as many columns as needed and spread them evenly on the grid.

Comment: I'd like each column to be at least 500px, and have them grow to occupy the full width of the grid. `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(500px, 1fr));` works just fine except that it prevents the columns from shrinking when their is only one column.